# How to get transfer function F(1/z) from F(z) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I defined a transfer function as following:

```
I =[1,zeros(1,65800)];
f = filter(num, den, I);
F = fftshift(fft(f));
```

Where F is F(z). Using F, how can I get F(1/z)?

Answer (score 0):

According to its [help page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#buagwwg-2), Matlab's `filter` command implements a rational transfer function specified by `num` and `den`. So there is no need to use `fft` to find your transfer function. It is

F(z) = (num(1) + num(2)*z^-1 + ...) / (1+ den(2)*z^-1 + ...)

If you want F(z^-1), substitute z^-1 into the above equation.